# How to let user select video thumbnail in android

Tags: android, android-layout, thumbnails, android-bitmap, video-thumbnails

My app allows users to upload videos to my server. Presently I use `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail` to create a thumbnail to upload with the video. How might I go about allowing the user to select a thumbnail?

I understand that I would use a RecyclerView or ListView with an Adapter. I get that much. But how do I go about loading them with thumbnails for the user to choose from?

Comment: Where are you looking to get these thumbnails? From the video itself or from their images?

Comment: From the video. That's what `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail` does. It comes standard with android. :)

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the same thing. Right now, it seems that I'll have to extend the default player, which is not really a route I'd like to go if I can avoid it.